# Using Drupal 7 hashing method in Drupal 6

Tags: 6

I want to use Drupal 7 hashing method in Drupal 6 for generating hash(not for password).
I will be using a key(say username) generate hash and store it in DB, later on when user provides username i will be generating hash for input and compare with the one that's stored in database.

```
include 'd7_modified_password.inc';
$key = "random_string";
print user_hash_password($key);
```

This generates a random string every time even though `$key` is unchanged. How can I use this so that I can use this method to compare two keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use `user_check_password()` method to compare existing key. Guess I overlooked it earlier.